# Will database indexes help in this context?

Tags: mysql, indexing, pivot, exists

I have a small to medium sized MySQL database where I don't update/insert very often, but select quite often. Recently, I've added a rather large EXISTS clause to one of the pages shown most often, and it really slows everything down - the query takes more than twenty seconds to run!

It's a database of persons who participates in camps. I have the persons in the table sct_persons, the camps in sct_camps, and the participations in sct_participants.

This is the (perhaps unsurprisingly) time-consuming SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sct_persons.id AS personid,
    sct_persons.name AS name,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=471 ) AS camp471,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=477 ) AS camp477,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=502 ) AS camp502,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=527 ) AS camp527,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=543 ) AS camp543,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=546 ) AS camp546,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=554 ) AS camp554,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=584 ) AS camp584,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=606 ) AS camp606,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=620 ) AS camp620,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=621 ) AS camp621,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=622 ) AS camp622,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=677 ) AS camp677,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=679 ) AS camp679,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=628 ) AS camp628,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=689 ) AS camp689,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=680 ) AS camp680,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=682 ) AS camp682,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=693 ) AS camp693,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=695 ) AS camp695,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=683 ) AS camp683,
    EXISTS( SELECT id FROM sct_participants WHERE person=personid AND camp=684 ) AS camp684
FROM sct_persons
JOIN sct_participants
ON sct_persons.id=sct_participants.person
WHERE camp=695
AND sct_participants.student=1
ORDER BY name;
```

I know this looks weird; what it does is that is first determines which other camps, if any, any of the camp participants have participated in, and creates a table with zeros and ones where they have or haven't previously participated.

I've been told that I can speed it up by using indexes, but I find all the available intros to indexes very abstract and difficult to understand, and I'm not sure it will be helpful in this instance.

Any help or comments will be appreciated!

Comment: If not already done, create indexes on sct_persons.id and sct_participants.person, sct_participants.camp, sct_participants.student will speed up for sure

Comment: Wow! It just went from over 20 seconds to under 2 seconds! Thank you very, very, very, very much!!! :-D I owe you one!

Comment: Just curious: How could you see that these were the columns that needed indexing? Can you just index all columns, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: These are the fields used in joins and used in where conditions.You can create an index combining more of them when the condition are often used together on those fields. 
I write the solution as an answer, to get some reputation grow ;-)

Comment: This query is _always_ going to be slow, because of the subselects. 2 seconds is shockingly slow for modern databases. I'd suggest rewriting this with outer joins, and doing the "rows to columns" pivot

Comment: You really need to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Which table is `WHERE camp=695` coming from??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not already done, create indexes on:

```
sct_persons.id
```

and

```
sct_participants.person, sct_participants.camp, sct_participants.student
```

This will speed up for sure because these are the fields used in joins and used in where conditions. You can create an index combining more of them when they are usually used togheter in the same join or condition.

Answer (score 0):

Start by building the non-pivoted query.  Then use that as a derived table to pivot the results.  Does this look correct for the first step?

```
SELECT
        s.id AS personid,
        s.name,
        t.id,
        t.camp
    FROM sct_persons AS s
    JOIN sct_participants AS t  ON s.id = t.person
    WHERE s.camp = 695
    AND t.student = 1
    ORDER BY s.name;
```

I removed the `DISTINCT` as being not needed??  And got lost on which columns were in which tables.  And I don't understand why there are two references to `sct_participants`; can it be done with just one?  You mention 3 tables, but your query shows only 2??

Please explain, in prose, what the goal is trying to do.